# How to create my own PTZ in C#

Tags: c#, opencv, aforge, ip-camera

I have camera ip with ptz.

How i can control it in my program (like: create GUI with arrows etc..)?
There is any function in OpenCV(EMGU) or in Aforge.NET to do this?

Comment: usually, your ip-cam should come with some http-rest like api for ptz movement. unfortunately , that's not standardizesed at all, so , definitely no support from the opencv api for that. you probably have to roll your own, but that should not be much of a problem, given c#

Comment: Mayby u can give me some sample? i cant find anything like this.
My camera: 3815W HD720